# Is there a way to point to document.styleSheets[].cssRules[] using a rule name?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I want to change a specific class-property-value using Javascript, but by the class-name itself and not with any integer as a pointer (cssRules[i]) or looping all classes to find the matching "selectorText" value.

This is for changing the readable on-screen language within the page.

```
<style id="languages" class="languages" title="languages">
<!--
    /* ... more styles ... */

    .lang-ita { display : none; }
    .lang-eng { display : none; }

    /* ... more styles ... */
-->
</style>

<script language="javascript">
<!--
    function fxSwitchLanguage(i)
    {
        /* ... more code ... */

        document.getElementById('languages').sheet.cssRules[i].style.setProperty('display','block');

        /* ... more code ... */
    }
-->
</script>

<button onClick="fxSwitchLanguage(0);">ITA</button>
<button onClick="fxSwitchLanguage(1);">ENG</button>
<br>
<div class="lang-ita">CIAO!</div>
<div class="lang-eng">HELLO!</div>
```

Of course I set the previous language "display" to "none" before showing only the new selected one.

I would like to have ".cssRules['.lang-eng']" instead of ".cssRules[i]".

Since this document is shared and may be changed by someone else, I really DO prefer to point the class using its name and not any hard-coded integer for obvious stability reasons, moreover I do not want to use a "for" cycle to test the "selectorText" property of each written class (can be easily thousands).

I don't mind any Browsers differences (.cssRules or .rules).

I just want to know if it is possible to have it in the way I'd prefer to.

Comment: I haven't worked too much with javascript's api into stylesheets, but I doubt you can address rules by key - mostly because multiple rules can have the same key.

Comment: If it is about a class, the costless method would be to override display inserting a new style sheet. Classname would be  the var to update. 'document.createElement("style")' ...

Comment: Yes Gershom, it is possible using an integer ( .cssRules[i] ); my examples wors fine but I'd really  prefer to use the "class-name" way, if possible.

Comment: Intresting way to do it, G-Cyr, I think I'll try it, yes. Thank you for the idea.

Comment: I would rethink your design. Instead of altering CSS rules like that, use a class on an ancestor element to control the display of the children. For example, have a class on body: `<body class="lang-ita">`, then update your rules to take advantage of that: `.lang-ita .lang-ita { display: block; } .lang-ita .lang-eng { display: none; }` (obviously add rules for when the body has the class "lang-eng", etc.). Then your switch language function just has to change the class on the body.

Comment: Nice way to think of it, I'm going to save your idea and use it for a lot of things. Thank you Heretic Money

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no CSSOM API to get a rule (or list of rules) by its selector string. Iterating them to find one is the only way. Of course you wouldn't do this in the `fxSwitchLanguage` function, everytime it is called, but outside of it, only once when the script is loaded. Then just store references to the relevant rules in a few constants, or a data structure.

But since your goal is to manipulate the rules by JavaScript, I'd go even further and also *create* them using javascript. That way, you can easily store a reference to them without iteration.

```js
const {sheet} = document.getElementById('languages');
const rules = new Map(['eng', 'ita', 'esp'].map(lang => {
  const rule = sheet.cssRules[sheet.insertRule(`.lang-${lang} {
    display: none;
  }`)]; // yes, it's weird, `insertRule` returns an index
  return [lang, rule];
}));

let active = null;
function fxSwitchLanguage(l) {
  if (active) rules.get(active).style.display = 'none';
  rules.get(l).style.display = 'block';
  active = l; 
} // or build a toggle or whatever
```

```html
<style id="languages">
</style>

<button onClick="fxSwitchLanguage('ita');">ITA</button>
<button onClick="fxSwitchLanguage('eng');">ENG</button>
<button onClick="fxSwitchLanguage('esp');">ESP</button>
<br>
<div class="lang-ita">CIAO!</div>
<div class="lang-eng">HELLO!</div>
<div class="lang-esp">HOLA!</div>
```

Comment: Now I know it is a "no-go" as I have indended and I appreciate your alternative way to do it; Than you for your simple and precise response to my question.

Comment: It is really intresting your way to interact with objects and structures.

Answer (score 0):

from comment here is the idea :

```js
function fxSwitchLanguage(varlang) {
  //* test if already created and remove it before update*/
  if (document.contains(document.getElementById("langSetting"))) {
    document.getElementById("langSetting").remove();
  }
  //* update language chosen*/
  var newStyle = document.createElement("style");
  newStyle.setAttribute("id", "langSetting"); //* put a mark on it */
  var addContent = ".lang-" + varlang + "{display:block;}";
  newStyle.appendChild(document.createTextNode(addContent));
  var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
  head.appendChild(newStyle);
}
```

```css
[class^='lang'] {display:none;}
```

```html
<button onClick="fxSwitchLanguage('ita');">ITA</button>
<button onClick="fxSwitchLanguage('eng');">ENG</button>
<hr>
<p class="lang-ita">CIAO!</p>
<div class="lang-eng">HELLO!</div>
```

Comment: Your code has made my brain burst of ideas, really appreciated. Thank you